# React-router check if can go back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there any way to know if there are any pages to go back to?

I have tried checking the value of `history.length`, assuming that any value greater than 1 means that we can still go back (including browser start pages). However, this solution doesn't cover cases where user has advanced several pages forward:

- Open the first page (`history.length === 1`)
- Go to the next page (`history.length === 2`)
- Go back one page (`history.length` is still 2)

I have also tried setting a timeout to check if there are any changes on the url & query params after a few millisecond (which work on most cases, but not all), and I was wondering if there is any better way to handle this.

Comment: It seems like the answer to this question could be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575215/access-react-router-history-stack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access React Router history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575215/access-react-router-history-stack)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, while the solution in that link sounds great, i was wondering if react router has any api to know whether we can go back or not

Answer (score 0):

Solution that works for `BroswerHistory` but uses the `history.entries` member which isn't [officially documented](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history):

```
function isHistoryRoot(history) {
  if (!history) return false;

  if (history.length === 1) return true;

  return history.location.pathname === history.entries[0].pathname;
}

const history = useHistory(); // react-router hook
const isRoot = isHistoryRoot(history);
```

Comment: will that cover this case? the catch is that we can go to the first page by clicking a link on the second page: Open the first page (history.length === 1) --> Go to the second page from the first page (history.length === 2) --> Go to the first page from the second page (history.length === 3).

`history.location.pathname === history.entries[0].pathname;` will return true, but we can actually still go back to the second page

Comment: @EdwinTandiono you are correct. This solution assumes a tree-like navigation pattern (forward and back) w/o any "loops" that allow you to go to a "previous" page using a forward link

Answer (score 0):

A bit old question, but problem is living for are centuries.

I've tryed to make smth similar - to show or not login popup before to open a page, if previous page this requires. But we havn't access to history length/stack.
[proof #1](https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/582#issuecomment-379271092)
[proof #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65335114/13398368)

Example (screenshot) - currently i'm got back from the /search and on /my-voyage page now. But in history stack this page **still not deleted**. If you will based on **entries** field or **length** field - you will have incorrect logic or calculations.

Solutions which i found,

1. to base our logic on **index** field. To get to know where we are. (my choice)
2. as @blundering-philosopher mentioned in comments, you can count goBack call's and store it on every page in **location.state**, and base logic on this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575215/access-react-router-history-stack)

[image: example of length and entries in react-router history]